# Cube root of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

how to prove that if $A\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ is a symmetric matrix, then there is $B\in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$ such that $B^3=A $

Thanks John, 
can you also give a hint for this question : how to find a real 3x3 matrix which doesn't have a real cube root?

Comment: Do you know how to diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: Real symmetric matrices have a very important property concerning diagonalization. Do yo know it ?

Comment: can you give me some hints ?

Comment: The answer to your question about how to find a real matrix that does not have a cube root can be found here:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441593/how-to-find-a-real-3-times3-matrix-that-has-no-cubic-root/1441625#1441625

Answer (score 5):

Hint: You know that a symmetric matrix $A$ can be diagonalized: there is an invertible matric $U$ so that

$$A = U D U^{-1},$$

where $D$ is a diagonal matrix with real coefficient. So if you can find $M$ so that $M^3  =D$, then $B= UMU^{-1}$ satisfy

$$B^3 = \big(UMU^{-1}\big)\big(UMU^{-1}\big)\big(UMU^{-1}\big) = UM^3U^{-1} = A$$

Comment: how to find a real 3x3 matrix which doesn't have a real cube root?