# Does an invertible real matrix have a real cubic root

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, cubics

$A$ is an invertible real matrix, is there a real matrix $B$ such that $A=B^3$?

For the complex case, it is not difficult. Over complex numbers, every invertible matrix has a cubic root.  In fact, over $\mathbb C$, since [every invertible matrix has a logrithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix#Existence), we can take a  family of matrices $e^{t\log A}$, and taking $t=1/3$ yields a square root of $A$.

The condition "invertible " is necessary for the real case. In fact,  here's a counterexample [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441593/how-to-find-a-real-3-times3-matrix-that-has-no-cubic-root).

How about general cases? $A$ is an invertible real matrix, is there a real matrix $B$ such that $A=B^n$, where integer $n\geq 2$?

Comment: Working with the real Jordan form of $A$ will be a good place to start.

Comment: I think you can assume it's upper-triangular, and then use the binomial formula, eg $(A+B)^{1/3}=A^{1/3}+\frac13A^{-2/3}B-\frac19 A^{-5/3}B^2+\frac{20}9A^{-8/3}B^3+\cdot$. Specifically, if $A$ is diagonal and $B$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It suffices to prove that $A$ is similar to a real matrix $C$ that can easily be seen to have a real cubic root $R$. So, if $P^{-1}CP=A$ and $R^3=C$, we may take $B=P^{-1}RP$.

Since all real matrices admit “real Jordan forms” (please consult *Matrix Analysis* by Horn and Johnson if you don't know what a real Jordan form is), it suffices to consider the case where $A$ is a real Jordan form with a single Jordan block. That is, we may assume that
$$
A=J_k(\lambda)=\pmatrix{\lambda&1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&1\\ &&&\lambda}
\quad\text{or}\quad
A=J_k(rQ_\theta)=\pmatrix{rQ_\theta&I_2\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&I_2\\ &&&rQ_\theta}
$$
where $\lambda$ is a nonzero real number, $r>0$ and $Q_\theta\ne\pm I_2$ is the $2\times2$ rotation matrix for angle $\theta$.

If $A=J_k(\lambda)$, take $R=J_k(\lambda^{1/3})$. Then $C$ and $A$ are similar because both of them are non-derogatory matrices with the same minimal polynomial $(x-\lambda)^k$. (That $\lambda\ne0$ is essential here. If $\lambda=0$, the minimal polynomial of $C=R^3$ is no longer $(x-\lambda)^k$ unless $k=1$).

Similarly, if $A=J_k(rQ_\theta)$, take $R=J_k(r^{1/3}Q_{\theta/3})$. Note that $A$ and $R$ are similar over $\mathbb C$ to
$$
J_k(re^{i\theta})\oplus J_k(re^{-i\theta})
\quad\text{and}\quad
J_k(r^{1/3}e^{i\theta/3})\oplus J_k(r^{1/3}e^{-i\theta/3})
$$
respectively. Thus the minimal polynomials of $A$ and $C$ (as $r\ne0$) are both equal to $(x-re^{i\theta})^k(x-re^{-i\theta})^k=\left(x^2-2r\cos(\theta)x+r^2\right)^k$. So, the two matrices are again similar because they are non-derogatory matrices with the same minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every real matrix that is diagonalizable over the complex numbers has a real cube root. Suppose $A$ is such a matrix. Then there is a real invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP =D$ where $D$ is a matrix that is 'almost' diagonal-it has real numbers $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m$ along the main diagonal and also (if it has one or more non-real eigenvalues) some 2x2 real blocks of the form $$\begin{bmatrix}a&-b\\b&a\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}r\cos\theta&-r\sin\theta\\r\sin\theta&r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}$$along the main diagonal and 0's elsewhere.Let $E$ be the matrix in which each $\lambda_i$ is replaced by $\lambda_i^{1/3}$ and each 2x2 block is replaced by $$r^{1/3}\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta/3)&-\sin(\theta/3)\\\sin(\theta/3)&\cos(\theta/3)\end{bmatrix}$$. Then $(PEP^{-1})^3=A$. Similarly the matrix $A$ has $\nu$-th roots if $\nu$ is any odd natural number.

Comment: What if it's not diagonalizable? For example $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ does have a cube root $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1/3\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$ but your method doesn't apply to it.

Comment: is there an $A$ which is an invertible real matrix, but there is no real matrix $B$ such that $A=B^3$?

Answer (score 0):

For square roots of real $A$ to exist, it is enough that all of the real eingenvalues of $A$ are $>0$.

Cubic roots, and more generally roots of odd order, exist for every real invertible $A$. The proof can be done like in the solution of @user1551.  A similar approach is using polynomials that do Hermite interpolation of the function $t\mapsto\sqrt[3]{t}$ on the spectrum of $A$ ( considered with multiplicities).

I tested an approach for cubic roots using the Newton method. That is, start with some $x_0$ ( perhaps $I$ if not a problem), and use the recurrence

$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^3-a}{3 x_n^2}$$

(the quotient since all of the $x_n$ commute with $a$).  It seems that the convergence is quite good.
This could work with other polynomial equations $P(B)= A$.

Another approach works if $A$ is not too far from $I$ , that is $A= I+\delta$, with $\delta$ small ( the spectral radius $\rho(\delta)<1$). Then we can take

$$\sqrt[n]{A} = \sqrt[n]{1+\delta}= (1+\delta)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \sum_{k\ge 0}\binom{\frac{1}{n}}{k} \delta^k$$